# Spring ORM JNDI Tomcat - No EntityManager with actual transaction available

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, spring-orm

I can find but i can't save my Entities.

Tomcat Context:

```
      <Resource name="jdbc/spring" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="spring" password="spring" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spitter"/>
```

DatabaseConfig and jpa config:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/spring");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter adapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.springinaction.spittr");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return  entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor paPostProcessor(){
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return properties;
    }
```

And DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public User findUser(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
        return (User)entityManager.createQuery("Select u from User u where username= :username ")
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("admin");
        user.setPassword("admin");
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRole("ADMIN");
        Role role2 = new Role();
        role2.setRole("USER");
        HashSet set = new HashSet();
        set.add(role);
        set.add(role2);
        user.setRoles(set);
        userRepository.addUser(user);
        return userRepository.findUserByUsername(s);
    }
}
```

When i am reaching userRepository.addUser(user) no entity is saved to my database and i got No EntityManager with actual transaction available exception.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i didn't put @EnableTransactionManagement() over my configuration.
Closed